# Controller action redirection when called via route

Tags: routes, controller, routing, redirect

I have a route set up in routes.php that calls a controller action using something similar to what is described here: https://straightupcraft.com/articles/how-do-i-setup-a-route-to-point-to-a-controller-action-instead-of-a-template

This works much better for my purposes than POSTing a form to the controller. However, I'm not sure how best to handle redirects. Ideally I would like to redirect back to the page where the user clicked on the link, but calling

```
$this->redirectToPostedUrl()
```

doesn't work when using a route like this. The URL just remains the URL as defined in the route.

Is there a different method I can use to make sure users are returned to the page where they were when they clicked the link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaken about how `redirectToPostedUrl` works... That's designed to redirect from a form submission, when the `redirect` field was supplied:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="page/to/redirect/to">
```

What you really want is this:

```php
$this->redirect(craft()->request->getUrlReferrer());
```

The `request->getUrlReferrer` method will actually retrieve the originating page URL.

Comment: Yup, I knew redirectToPostedUrl wasn't what I needed, but just wasn't quite sure where to turn. This looks like exactly what I needed though, thank you!

Comment: Cool, no problem! :)

Comment: Note that `request->getUrlReferrer` actually uses the request headers from the browser, so you cannot assume that it exists and/or is reliable 100% of the time. To ensure you redirect back to the appropriate page you will need to include that hidden "redirect" input in your form.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need this for CraftCMS version 3, as I did today, the code slightly changed:

```
$this->redirect(Craft::$app->getRequest()->referrer);
```

This works fine with version 3.